# how ctags parse class definition with macro, for c++

Tags: c++, ctags

In my project i have code like the following:

```
class SOME_MACRO Abc {
  // all the common c++ stuf
}
```

and my ctags usage is like:

```
ctags -R --sort=yes --c++-kinds=+plx --c-kinds=+plx --fields=+iaS --extra=+q
```

The tags generated do not contain the definition for Abc.
So my question is how to make ctags to correctly parse classes like above?
can ctags do this ? if not , do you have some recommendation?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I think you only need to use the `-I SOME_MACRO` option to ignore "SOME_MACRO".